# $.ajax parseerror on {"vErrorsFound":true,"vMessage":"Login Failed"}

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I am upgrading from jQuery 1.3.2 to jQuery 1.5 and I can't get JSON to parse.  With $.ajax I am calling a php script that returns the following via the PHP json_encode method:

```
{"vErrorsFound":true,"vMessage":"Login Failed"}
```

I have tried simplifying the object to:
`{"vErrorsFound":true}` alone and `{"vMessage":"Login Failed"}` alone but I still get a parse Error from the ajax call.

Here's the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
       url : "index_vld.php",
       data: {Username: $("input[name=Username]").val(), Password: $("input[name=Password]").val()},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
       {
           alert(data);
       },
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
       {
           alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
       }
       });
```

I found out that JSON parsing is much stricter in the newer version of jquery however I cannot find out what's wrong in this simple json object returned from the PHP script.  I have also tried setting the content type of the php script to application/json without success.

The exception thrown reads: jQuery15045727721066214144_1298305275108 was not called.

Can't upgrade to jQuery 1.5 before I solve this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you set your headers on the php script to application/json, it may not be recognizing what's returned as json

Comment: @Austin: He's telling jQuery explicitly to treat it as JSON: `dataType: 'json'`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I set the content header and also the datatype without success on jquery 1.5 but everthing's ok with 1.4.4.  I just wanted to use the latest version of jquery now that i decided to upgrade coz there's a lot of work to do and the later the release the farther will the next upgrade be!

Comment: What I get is exactly what I said: Error event handler fires with the errors I specified i.e. parseerror in textstatus and jQuery15045727721066214144_1298305275108 was not called in errorThrown.  I am 100% that datatype is set to json and not jsonp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same behavior with my Ajax requests updating from jQuery 1.4.4 to 1.5.1. Alexey's answer worked for the short term, but the Ajax rewrite in jQuery 1.5 makes that solution suboptimal for prolonged use.

If you are using jQuery + the jQuery Validation plugin and continue to experience this error, try grabbing the latest Validation source from https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation. I pulled the source, dropped into my app, and now I'm getting much more consistent Ajax responses.

Comment: It's true.  It seems they fixed it in the latest version of the plugin..  Great.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.m0sa.net/2011/02/jqueryvalidation-breaks-jquery-15-ajax.html

> The cause of the problem is this line
>   of JavaScript in jQuery.validate.js,
>   that overrides the settings you pass
>   into the $.ajax call with all the
>   default ones (and jQuery.ajaxSettings
>   defaults to { jsonp: "callback",
>   jsonpCallback: function() {...}}):

The workaround:

```
$(function () {
  $.ajaxSettings.cache = false;
  $.ajaxSettings.jsonp = undefined;
  $.ajaxSettings.jsonpCallback = undefined;
})
```

Comment: The workaround is not quite neat because these changes influence all ajax calls and not only the jquery.validate calls.  To make these changes before validation and set them back to the original state after validation is quite un-neat and if I look at the code in 3 months time I would probably find those lines of code ridiculous.  Ideally the jquery.validate control is fixed such that one can choose between cross-site validation and local validation.

Comment: Had the same problem. Updating jquery.validate.js to the latest version fixed it.  Never in a million years would I have caught that.  Thanks Alexey.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the JSON you quoted. ([jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com/) is a handy place to check that sort of thing.)

The error message you're quoting sounds like a JSON-P problem; did you edit the `dataType` before posting your question? Because it sounds like jQuery thinks you're trying to do JSON-P (`dataType: "jsonp"`). [More here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Or perhaps you have some [global ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) set to do JSON-P?

**Edit**: Your code as quoted works fine: http://jsbin.com/ocapo5

Comment: I've tried both jsonp and json without success.  Now I have downloaded jquery 1.4.4 and it works fine.  I think it could be a jquery 1.5 issue because the strict handling of json was not introduced in jquery 1.5 but in 1.4.1 or so.  So if it were a wrongly formatted json object, jquery 1.4.4 would have complained anyway.

Comment: @user: As I said, there's nothing wrong with your JSON. The working example I linked is using jQuery 1.5 (at the moment; I actually told it to use whatever the latest 1.x is, but at the moment it's 1.5). Here's a version that says what it's using: http://jsbin.com/ocapo5/2 And here's one future-proofed to always use 1.5: http://jsbin.com/ocapo5/3 The error you quoted is related to JSON-P, it must be from when you were doing `dataType: 'jsonp'`; what do you get when you actually run the code you quoted in your question?

Comment: I have retried to make double sure datatype is not jsonp and now I can confirm that what I get is exactly what I said before: Error event handler fires with the errors I specified i.e. "parseerror" in textstatus and "jQuery15045727721066214144_1298305275108 was not called" in errorThrown. I am 100% that datatype is set to json and not jsonp.  I checked out yours and I have no idea why yours is working and why mine is not.

Comment: @user: That is so weird. :-) Something, somewhere, is getting in the way. An `ajaxSetup` call, a bad download, *something*. Good luck with it.

Comment: I am not calling ajaxsetup in my scripts and to check if it's a bad download most probably I'll have to check the raw http request and headers.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the data type to dataType: 'text' and use JSON.parse to parse my json string into javascript object and it is working fine

```
success: function (data) {myObject=JSON.parse(data);}
```